# Is it possible to measure the temperature of a candle by the diffraction method?

Tags: optics, temperature, laser, refraction, diffraction

I am reading a book " Physics, Fun and Beyond" by Eduardo de Campos Valadares. In his book, he is mentioning about an experiment "bending laser beams with hot air." I am posting a figure used in his book. I wonder it is possible to measure the temperature of the candle's flame. The refractive index will change with temperature but I don't know how to use this information to calculate the path difference. The temperature will change along the path of laser due to irregularity of the temperature of the candle flame. In the theory, we may neglect the change of the temperature in the experiment.

[image]

Comment: "by the diffraction method" the deflection of a ray because of changing refractive index is refraction. Diffraction is a different phenomenon. 
"we may neglect the change of the temperature [along the laser path in the heated region]" If we do this we can definitely compute a number, but it will not be anything remotely close to measuring the temperatures of the heated region.

Comment: For an actual, precise implementation of the experiment check out: [“Study of the refractive index distribution of air around a candle flame”](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235347810_Study_of_the_refractive_index_distribution_of_air_around_a_candle_flame)